# d3.js force graph : links spreading the graph too much

Tags: d3.js, graph

I want to display a set of nodes in a force-directed graph.Those nodes have almost exclusively a parent-child relationship (almost a tree).There are a few nodes which have many children, and most others are leaves.
This produces a structure of several interconnected node "islands".The problem is, those "islands" keep spreading apart, specially when nodes are dragged.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/50oz3xtr/
I've been trying different settings in the following block:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
.force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
```

But without luck (strength, distanceMin...)

My questions are:
- How can i set a "max length" on links, so the graph doesnt spread too much?
- Is there a way to set a "fixed" length to links?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do  is to set a "ideal" length on each link which the simulation will try to optimise to.

To do this, chain the distance method to the end of your "link" force - [api reference](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#link_distance)

e.g.

```
.force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance({x}));
```

You can also pass in a function to the distance method, which allows you to vary ideal distances on a link by link basis.

Also, bear in mind that you have more than one force acting here, so other forces may "interfere" with your link force. I would look at playing with the "strength" setting on each link, and consider using a "collide" force instead of many body.

Playing with the parameters to each force should get you the result you are after.

Comment: In fact, i have a test using that approach, but the results are the same.What it's different, is the initial layout. But as soon as i click a node to drag it (even if dont drag it at all), the simulation continues running and ends up in a similar estructure (node islands interconnected by very long "strings"), even if i fix the link distance with forceLink().distance()

Comment: I am suggesting you try something like this: var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(10))
    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(10))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));
Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/50oz3xtr/1/